# Multiplying by an Integer by a Float/Double in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to do something so simple: multiply an integer by a float/double:

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x =  (int) 0.5 * 100;       
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

However, although you'd expect this to return `x = 50`, instead `x = 0`! The same thing happens when I use `float d = 0.5f`. Does anyone know what is going on and why this isn't working?

Comment: I think java casts the second term in the * operation to match the first. Try `int x = (int) (d * a);` or `int x = (int) (a * (float) (d))`

Comment: Are you serious? This is not possible. Did you even try running? It will give 50!!!

Comment: I changed the code to get straight to the point of the problem. I have updated the code to reflect the problem more accurately.

Comment: @ioanD No. The order is immaterial. It widens the result to the wider of the two types.

Comment: Sorry guys, there is no problem. Moderator, can you delete?

Comment: Delete the question by yourself.

Answer (score 16):

[JLS §4.2.4. Floating-Point Operations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.4) tell rules governing floating point operation, so as per that if any of the operand is a floating point number than other operand will be widened to a floating point (if not already) and final result will be a floating point number.

So, your `int` `100` will be widened to `100.0` before arithmetic operation, and your result of operation will be `50.0`.

Now, since you are casting your result to in `int`, so [JSL §5.1.3. Narrowing Primitive Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) will be applicable, and double `50.0` will be narrowed to int `50`.

100 is an impossible result, given the code you have provided.

My guess is that when you got 100, you would have done something else.

[image]

Comment: You're right. I should have mentioned that 'a' is a static integer... I changed the code to get straight to the point of the problem.

Comment: @alwaysboots Can you please update your question with correct code, if you still have doubt. I have provided you JLS links for rule, have a look.

Comment: @alwaysboots Buddy, still it would be 50. Making it static will only change the way it can be accessed, means you need not to have an class instance to access it. Any rule related to primitive operation will not change.

Comment: I think you are missing something on how you got 100.

Answer (score 4):

```
int x =  (int) 0.5 * 100;
```

it first casts 0.5 to an int ---> 0 then multiplies.

Comment: Converting a float to an int truncates everything after the decimal. Not sure if that is very helpful. Perhaps rather convert both to a float and do the calculation first, and then decide how you want to lose precision. See my answer below.

Comment: ??? The result of this code is 0, not the expected result of 50. How did this incorrect Answer get five upvotes?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the operands to the same types first.

```java
float f = 0.5 * 100f;
```

or

```java
float f = 0.5 * (float)100;
```

You can't really "convert" a float to an integer without potentially losing some precision, so you'll meed to decide how you want to deal with the loss of precision. The java Math object can help:

```java
int rounded = Math.round(0.5 * 100f);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're casting `0.5f` to `int` before doing the mutiplication. So, you're effectively doing:

```java
int x = ((int) 0.5) * 100;

int x = 0 * 100; // <-- which is basically the same as this
```

This happens because the cast operator `(int)` has a [higher precedence](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/) than the multiplication `*` operator.

If you want the integer result of the float operation, then you'd have to do:

```java
int x = (int)(0.5 * 100);
```

This would automatically cast `100` to a float (`100f`), then multiply both floats `0.5 * 100.0 = 50.0`, and then finally cast the result to `int`.

Then, you'd have: `x = 50`